# Can only drag and drop rows that are on the unlocked side of kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid that uses frozen/locked columns and has drag and drop functionality. The problem is that I can only drag and drop a row on the side where columns are unlocked and this is not what I want. I would like to be able to grab a row from the locked side and drag and drop. IE, if I grab a row from the ID column, I should be able to drag and drop that.
I hope that make sense

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $.when(LoadGrid()).then(EnableDragAndDropForGrid());
});

let ds = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 25,
    gender: "female",
    city: "London"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    age: 26,
    gender: "male",
    city: "London"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "James",
    lastname: "Jones",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
    city: "New York"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Mary",
    lastname: "Johnson",
    age: 23,
    gender: "female",
    city: "Paris"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Robert",
    lastname: "Lee",
    age: 44,
    gender: "male",
    city: "Berlin"
  }
];

function LoadGrid() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          id: {
            type: "number"
          },
          name: {
            type: "string"
          },
          lastname: {
            type: "string"
          },
          age: {
            type: "number"
          },
          gender: {
            type: "string"
          },
          city: {
            type: "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        title: "id",
        field: "id",
        width: 100,
        locked: true
      },
      {
        title: "First",
        field: "name",
        locked: true,
        width: 150
      },
      {
        title: "Last",
        field: "lastname",
        locked: true,
        width: 150
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        field: "age",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        title: "Gender",
        field: "gender",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        title: "City",
        field: "city",
        width: 100
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: ds
    },
    sortable: true
  });
}

function EnableDragAndDropForGrid() {
  let grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
  grid.table.kendoSortable({
    filter: ">tbody >tr",
    hint: function(element) {
      let table = $('<table style="width: 600px;" class="k-grid k-widget"></table>'),
        hint;

      table.append(element.clone());
      table.css("opacity", 0.7);

      return table;
    },
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function(element) {
      return $('<tr colspan="4" class="placeholder"></tr>');
    },
    change: function(e) {
      let skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
        oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
        newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
        data = grid.dataSource.data(),
        dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

      grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
      grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

    }
  });
}
```

```css
.k-grid tbody tr {
  cursor: move;
}

.placeholder {
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-color: red;
}

#grid {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure I think that is by design, I mean, it should work like that. Could not find any resource about it, tho.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, I looked all over for a solution to this and haven't come across anything for this. I hope that there is some way to do what I need. If worse comes to worse then I'll have to put in a ticket for support and see what happens

Comment: Sent in a support ticket to Telerik, if there is a solution I will post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is

> The reason for the behaviour is that the Kendo UI Grid with locked columns creates two tables and currently the sortable widget is initialized over the table that holds the non-locked content.
>
> To initialize the drag and drop over the locked table, we need to use the lockedTable element.
>
> If you want the user to see the full row, you can get the corresponding cells from the other table by looking for the row with the same data-uid

```
function EnableDragAndDropForGrid() {
  let grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
  console.log(grid)
  grid.lockedTable.kendoSortable({
    filter: ">tbody >tr",
    hint: function(element) {
      var unlockedPortion = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + element.data("uid") + "]").children();
      
      let table = $('<table style="width: 600px;" class="k-grid k-widget"></table>'),
        hint;

      table.append(element.clone().append(unlockedPortion));
      table.css("opacity", 0.7);

      return table;
    },
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function(element) {
      return $('<tr colspan="4" class="placeholder"></tr>');
    },
    change: function(e) {
      let skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
        oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
        newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
        data = grid.dataSource.data(),
        dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

      grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
      grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I sort of like this solution, however there is an issue with the placeholder as it doesn't span the locked and unlocked columns.

Comment: @Lee, I have noticed that it only spans either side which sucks from a UI perspective

Comment: I solved for this and posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved this by creating a function that can be called after creating a draggable grid with locked columns. Unfortunately the grid's rowReorder event is never called.

Like this:

```
let myGrid = $("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
   reorderable: {
      rows: true,
   },
   rowReorder: function(ev) {
     // doesn't seem to work with locked columns.
   },
   // rest of options
}).data("kendoGrid");
//Optionally pass a callback function as the second parameter. 
//It will get the same parameters as the rowReorder function should have gotten.
enableKendoGridLockedDND("#myGrid", reorderHappened);
function reorderHappened(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Here is the function:

```
// You can pass a function as the second parameter which will be called on change.
// The on change function will receive information from the change event and
// pass it back as a parameter to the function you pass.
// Access it like myFunction(e). 

function enableKendoGridLockedDND(gridElement, onChangeFunction) {
    if (!gridElement) {
        gridElement = ".k-grid";
    }
    let grid = $(gridElement).data("kendoGrid");
    if (!grid.lockedTable) {
        console.info("The function enableKendoGridLockedDND was called on a table without any locked columns");
        return false;
    }
    let gridWidth = $(gridElement).width();
    let lockedWidth = $(gridElement).find(".k-grid-header-locked").width() || 0;
    let unlockedWidth = $(gridElement).find(".k-grid-header-wrap table").width() || 0;
    let tableWidth = lockedWidth + unlockedWidth + 2;
    let placeholderPosition = null;
    grid.lockedTable.kendoSortable({
        axis: "y",
        filter: ">tbody >tr",
        hint: function(element) {
            let unlockedPortion = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + element.data("uid") + "]").children();
            let hint = $(`<div style="overflow: hidden; width: ${gridWidth}px;"><table style="background: whitesmoke; width: ${tableWidth}px;" class="k-grid k-widget"></table></div>`);
            let colgroups = $(gridElement).find(".k-grid-header colgroup");
            let colgroupWidths = [];
            $.each(colgroups, function (index, group) {
                $.each($(group).children(), function (index2, child) {
                    colgroupWidths.push($(child).css("width"));
                });
            });
            hint.find("table").append(element.clone().append(unlockedPortion.clone()));
            $.each(hint.find("td"), function (index, col) {
                $(col).css("width", colgroupWidths[index]);
            });
            hint.css("opacity", 0.7);
            return hint;
        },
        cursor: "move",
        placeholder: function (element) {
            var unlockedRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + element.data("uid") + "]");
            $(unlockedRow).before($(unlockedRow).clone().attr("data-uid", "").addClass("k-hover unlocked-placeholder"));
            $(unlockedRow).hide();
            let placeholder = element.clone();
            $(placeholder).attr("data-uid", "");
            return placeholder;
        },
        move: function (e) {
            //Set positions
            let lastPosition = placeholderPosition;
            placeholderPosition = this.indexOf(this.placeholder);
            let itemPosition = this.indexOf(e.item);
            let targetPosition = this.indexOf(e.target);

            //Get Elements
            let unlockedDraggingRow = $(gridElement).find(".k-grid-content tr.unlocked-placeholder");
            let targetElement = $(gridElement).find(".k-grid-content tr[data-uid=" + e.target.data("uid") + "]");

            //Find direction of move
            let movingUp = false; 
            if (lastPosition === null) {
                if (itemPosition > targetPosition) {
                    movingUp = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (lastPosition > placeholderPosition) {
                    movingUp = true;
                }
            }

            //Move the unlocked row
            if (movingUp) {
                targetElement.before(unlockedDraggingRow);
            } else {
                targetElement.after(unlockedDraggingRow);
            }
        },
        change: function (e) {
            let skip = grid.dataSource.skip() || 0;
            let newIndex = e.newIndex + skip;
            let dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));
            grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

            // Custom function to call
            if (typeof onChangeFunction === "function") {
                e.skip = skip;
                e.newWithSkip = newIndex;
                e.oldWithSkip = e.oldIndex + skip;
                onChangeFunction(e);
            }
        },
        start: function () {
            placeholderPosition = null;
        }
    });
}
```

I also posted a version of this answer here: [Telerik Kendo UI Jquery Forum][https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-with-locked-columns-and-drag-and-drop]